# Как здесь сделать чтобы при увеличении футер не налегал на всё остальное?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bigtext.js"></script>
   <style>
html,body{
   margin:0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

html{height: 100%;border-style: solid;
border-color: #58cdcd;
border-width: 1px;} 
body{position: relative; 
  min-height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
border-color: #cd5858;
border-width: 1px;

}

.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    /*background-color: rgba(180, 215, 255, 0.096);*/
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #383535;
    font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
    /*color: rgb(233, 181, 38);*/
    border-style: solid;
border-color: #cacd58;
border-width: 1px;
}
.footer a{
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  vertical-align: middle;
color: #383535;
/*color: rgb(233, 181, 38);*/
}

.footer a:hover{
 /* color: rgba(6, 31, 100, 0.425);*/
 color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.781);
 /*color: rgba(233, 181, 38, 0.671);*/
}

  #page {

   

    margin: 36px auto;

width: 90%;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #58cd58;
border-width: 1px;
padding-bottom: 800px;
}

.blog {

margin: 0 auto 53px;

width: 93,75%; /* 900px / 960px */
border-style: solid;
border-color: #58bbcd;
border-width: 1px;
}

.blog .main {
  
  float: left;  width: 62.8888889%;  /* 566px / 900px */

}

.blog .other {
  
float: right;  width: 36.7777778%;  /* 331px / 900px */

}
.lede {

padding: 0.8em 5.33333333%; /* 48px / 900px */
border-style: solid;
border-color: #080806;
border-width: 1px;
}
.recent-entries {
  
margin: 0 auto;
width: 69.7885196%; /* 231px / 331px */
border-style: solid;
border-color: #cd5858;
border-width: 1px;
}
.article {
padding: 0 8.48056537%; 


/* 48px /
566px */}

.date {
  float: left;
  
  
  margin: 24px 0 0 -17.0886076%;  /* 81px / 474px */  
  width: 14.556962%;  /* 69px / 474px */
border-style: solid;
border-color: #e7e725;
border-width: 1px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">  
        <div class="blog section"> 
            
            <h1 class="lede">Recently in <a href="#">The Bot Blog</a></h1>
            <div class="main">
            
            <div class="article">
                <div class="date">
                    <h1>34</h1>
                    
                  </div>
                <a>fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf</a>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /end .main -->

            <div class="other">
              <div class="recent-entries">
<a>fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf fgggggggg
  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg</a>
</div>
            </div><!-- /end .other -->  
          </div><!-- /end .blog.section -->
          
          <div class="footer"><a>fOOTER</a>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /end #page -->

    
        
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: float наверно для сетки забыть надо ..его применять только для обтекания, для построение сетки использовать flexbox или grid

Comment: если нужен текст то есть lorem ipsum

Comment: если хотите что бы подвал фиксировался то достаточно прописать position: sticky и bottom: 0

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/GbQwqm реализация фиксируемого подвала